# Angular 2.0 performance

Tags: angular

I'm totally new to Angular 2.0 and I just playing around with it to see if I should implement a project using Angular 2.0.

I have a question regarding its performance. I've setup https://angular.io/guide/quickstart on my Windows setup, using ASP.NET 5 and the DNX engine to serve the pages and I just got it to work, but I'm horrified how slow it runs. It's just a simple component that prints "My First Angular 2 App" and it takes about 5 seconds every time I load the page. At first I thought it was because of a lot of requests, but it's only 6 requests and since it runs locally, shouldn't it run almost instantly?

I know it's still in beta, but if that performance is normal, I can't see how anyone can use that in a serious solution.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using typescript and the files are transpiled before using gulp-typescript. I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I am doing the same, but with php and apache....it is slow too, even for a simple `Hello World` app...I am thinking on stay with AngularJS for now...

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Do you have an idea on how to make it run faster? I've just run some simple tests and it looks very heavy on the memory usage and uses a lot of CPU cycles just for the Hello World sample. Maybe I haven't configured it correctly. As I said, I'm totally new to this :-) I'm reading a lot of books right now in order to use it, but if this is the performance level, I don't think I'm able to use it.

Comment: It seems to run better now, but it still varies from about 1,5 sec to max 5 seconds to load it.

Comment: What time are you measuring?

Comment: Integrating .NET with Angular2 isn't an easy process, and there a lot of very wrong ways of doing it (you can find plenty of bad architectured opinions online) Check out http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/ the best implementation out there. Steve is also an ASPNET member. The repo also uses Universal (for server-side rendering) the Angular2 application for quicker paints. `npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa webpack` then `cd some-empty-directory` install the generator `yo aspnetcore-spa` Voila.

Comment: If you're using gulp, you're already using an outdated way of using Angular2 (with or without .NET)

Comment: I'm just using the browser's developer tools for performance and memory. It seems to be more stable around the 1,5 sec now so maybe it's just my machine that's slow

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you very much. Shouldn't I use gulp for Angular? I've found a lot of samples of that. How should I do it then.

Comment: I can't see what .NET has to do with it right now. I just tested it being served from a .html file and from and route in my mvc app and the load time is the same as far as I can see.

Comment: Install that generator and take a look. You want to use webpack to handle all of that, hot module reloading, it's all even integrated with .NET. All of this will already be done for you as well, you can just take your time learning how it was accomplished (afterwards). Can't beat that :)

Comment: Also you're most likely not running Angular2 in `productionMode`. You're seeing everything slower because it's including all kinds of debugging code / compiler information / etc.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try that. Thank you very much. I did see Steven Sanders talks but didn't try this.

Comment: `import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core'; enableProdMode();`